# what does unauthenticated user mean in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+-----+----------------------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User                 | Host               | db   | Command | Time | State                            | Info                  |
+-----+----------------------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
|   1 | system user          |                    | NULL | Connect |  623 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL                  | 
|   2 | system user          |                    | NULL | Connect |    0 | Reading event from the relay log | NULL                  | 
| 400 | root                 | localhost          | v3   | Sleep   |   68 |                                  | NULL                  | 
| 585 | root                 | localhost          | v3   | Query   |    0 | NULL                             | show full processlist | 
| 748 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32833  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 749 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32836  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 750 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32838  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 751 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32841  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 752 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32844  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 753 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32846  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 754 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32848  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 755 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46827 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 756 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46830 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 757 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46831 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 758 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32857  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 759 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32858  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 760 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32859  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 761 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32863  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 762 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32864  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 763 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32866  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 764 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32870  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 765 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32871  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 766 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46833 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 767 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32878  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 768 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32881  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 769 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32885  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 770 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46835 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 771 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32888  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 772 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32890  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 773 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46837 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 774 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46839 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 775 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46841 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 776 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46844 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 777 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46845 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 778 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46847 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 779 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32898  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 780 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32900  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 781 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46850 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 782 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46852 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 783 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46854 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 784 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46857 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 785 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46859 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 786 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32903  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 787 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46862 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 788 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46865 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 789 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46866 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 790 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46868 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 791 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46871 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 792 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46873 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 793 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32907  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 794 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32909  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 795 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32911  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 796 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46875 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 797 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32914  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 798 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.27:32916  | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 799 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46877 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
| 800 | unauthenticated user | 172.19.0.139:46879 | NULL | Connect | NULL | login                            | NULL                  | 
+-----+----------------------+--------------------+------+---------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
57 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 34):

A connection with "unauthenticated user" in the User column has initiated a connection but hasn't sent his/her credentials yet, so the server doesn't know who exactly is connecting.

If such connections only showed up in the list when they were authenticated, it could potentially run the server out of available sockets and you wouldn't even know why.

Most often stuck connections are due to [DNS not resolving properly, which the skip-name-resolve option will help with](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve).

[More info](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221180404/http://www.pythian.com/blog/what-is-an-unauthenticated-user) at the Pythian blog.

Comment: You mean when we connect to db,it's splited into 2 steps?

Comment: 4 actually, according to the Pythian blog article.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I've been struggling with a MySQL server that was choking and acting like it was out of memory, proc, or disk, but they were fine. It was that we have 4 web servers that connect over the local network and MySQL was getting stuck trying to DNS resolve the private ip addresses. I chose to skip-name-resolve because I didn't need it. Could probably also just add those host names to /etc/hosts as well

Comment: 404's on both links.

Comment: @RNickMcCandless I've fixed both broken links, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you may need to use skip-name-resolve, as mysql is trying to resolve the mysql host address, or add the hostname being connected to in the file /etc/hosts, or both. bonus: fix any problems with your DNS that are causing the lookups to time out in the first place

Comment: Actually, this is shown even when connecting via localhost or socket, which doesn't use the [host cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html)

Answer (score 4):

We had this problem on our production database.  It turned out to be SSL on the connections to the database.  We were opening a lot of connections to the database due to high web traffic (no connection pooling in Django) - guess the server got bogged down with the initial SSL handshakes.  When we turned off SSL to the database things started flying through.

Comment: In my case I had to disable SSL on the client: `mysql --skip-ssl`

Comment: Ok, but this is not exactly a best practices advice, quite the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

You have a low thread_cache_size (number of mysql start threads) or max_connexion and mysql can't make a new thread is in the process of creating new threads to handle those connextions

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the *skip-name-resolve* can resolve your problem but it wasn't my case.

This message : "unauthenticated user" on **User** column with "show processlist" can mean that you are using old encryption password.

In my case, I recreated my users with new encryption format, like that :

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DA7CC43A56959FE78FC336FB9D7185AAACCC44DD';
```

or simply with it if you don't have used "old password" in your configuration.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Answer (score -2):

I added `skip_name_resolve = 1` to my.cnf, which solved my problem.