# MySQL unauthenticated user

Tags: mysql

**Problem**

 
MySQL is showing many unauthenticated users.

**Set up**

 
Load Balance server that points to 5 webservers
All connected to 1 database/files server.

**Info**

 
It seems only requests from servers 1 and 2 are having the unauthenticated user problem.  Servers 3,4 & 5 are working fine but looks like their users are staying in the process list.  Is there any reason why only 2 of the servers would be acting up?

```
+--------+------------------- --+----------------------+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
| Id     | User                 | Host                 | db       | Command   | Time | State   | Info |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
| 171733 | unauthenticated user | web.1.IP.HERE:50038  | NULL     | Connect   | NULL | login   | NULL |
| 171735 | unauthenticated user | web.1.IP.HERE:50039  | NULL     | Connect   | NULL | login   | NULL |
| 171736 | unauthenticated user | web.1.IP.HERE:60721  | NULL     | Connect   | NULL | login   | NULL |
| 171737 | unauthenticated user | web.2.IP.HERE:50040  | NULL     | Connect   | NULL | login   | NULL |
| 171746 | unauthenticated user | web.2.IP.HERE:60723  | NULL     | Connect   | NULL | login   | NULL |
| 181337 | username             | web.3.IP.HERE:34426  | dbName   | Sleep     |    4 |         | NULL |
| 181339 | username             | web.3.IP.HERE:51668  | dbName   | Sleep     |    4 |         | NULL |
| 181340 | username             | web.4.IP.HERE:51669  | dbName   | Sleep     |    4 |         | NULL |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
```

I have seen the mention of `skip-name-resolve` but when I run `select user, host FROM mysql.user` I only see IPS or "localhost" in the host column so i dont see how that would fix it.

Overall the processlist still seems high with other users as well but under "info" it says NULL.  Anyway to clear these?

Comment: How do you grants look like?

Comment: @frlan - There is one entry and it says @'localhost'

Comment: Well... Than none of your webservers should be able to direct access the database. Obviously, it's not the case

Comment: @frlan - I ran SHOW GRANTS but didn't realize that was for the user logged in.  As root I ran select * from information_schema.user_privileges; I only see localhost or IPS.

Comment: Are all of your webservers listed in IP part?

Comment: @frlan - There is something like this XXX.XX.127.192/255.255.255.224 ( Those are not X's of course I just masked part of it )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does unauthenticated user mean in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983400/what-does-unauthenticated-user-mean-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, Here is the issue and how to resolve it.. it took me a month and i've been looking all over

A connection with "unauthenticated user" in the User column has initiated a connection but hasn't sent his/her credentials yet, so the server doesn't know who exactly is connecting.

If such connections only showed up in the list when they were authenticated, it could potentially run the server out of available sockets and you wouldn't even know why.

Most often stuck connections are due to DNS not resolving properly, which the skip-name-resolve option will help with.

More info at the Pythian blog.

use skip-name-resolve in my.cf and that should resolve your problem.

Comment: `skip-name-resolve` really saved the day for me. The interesting thing is that for one server, it was no problem, but for an other (the backup server), all connections from the php clients were stuck in the login state...